# Why is splice working with for loop, but not with map in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

For a 2D array:

```
var fruits = [["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Pear"],
["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Pear"],
["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Pear"],
["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Pear"]];
```

why the difference between `map` and `for loop`?

```
var newArrayMap = fruits.map(f => f.splice(1,2));
console.log(newArray);


[["Orange", "Apple"], ["Orange", "Apple"], ["Orange", "Apple"], ["Orange", "Apple"]]
```

```
for (var i = fruits.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        fruits[i].splice(1,2);
    }
console.log(fruits);

[["Banana", "Pear"], ["Banana", "Pear"], ["Banana", "Pear"], ["Banana", "Pear"]]
```

Comment: splice returns the deleted parts of the array.

Comment: I'm using ```splice``` in both, no?

Comment: `map` uses return value of callback function as a value for a new array, return value of `map` itself. Note that if you log value of `fruits` in your first example, you'll see exactly the same result as in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns the deleted parts of the array.

In the first loop with `map`, you take the returned value of `splice`.

In the second loop with `for`, you never use the returned value of `splice`. `splice` mutates the array and because of that, you get an array without unwanted parts.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought the returned value of ```splice``` was a mutated array.  Is there a resource that will explain this to me like I'm a five-year-old?

Comment: i think the link above should help. just have a look to retun value and what the method is doing. just try with raw data and look to the result.